# I want to remove xml tag using XSLT based on condition

Tags: xml, xslt

From the following xml file i want to delete "centrum" tag from biilingbatch based on one condition. Condition is if is 1921 then i wantto delete centrum tag from XML. In xml there are many centrum tag under different different Parent tag. I want to delete that centrum tag whoes parent tag is billingbatch.
My xml is:

```
<calculate>
        <calculateAmount>
          <currency>978</currency>
          <individualAmount>-10000</individualAmount>
          <billingType>1</billingType>
          <billingPeriodEndDate>20260214</billingPeriodEndDate>
          <extMvmtFinInstMode>8</extMvmtFinInstMode>
        <billingbatch>
                        <Account>1921</Account>
                        <Centrum>LBNG</Centrum>
                        <Company>LNS</Company>
                        <TextCode>570</TextCode>
                        <TextData>952491</TextData>
        </billingbatch>

        <calculatebillingbatch>
                <Account>1921</Account>
                        <Centrum>LBNG</Centrum>
                        <Company>LNS</Company>
                        <TextCode>570</TextCode>
                        <TextData>952491</TextData>
        </calculatebillingbatch>
        </calculateAmount>
```

Expected result is:

```
<calculate>
        <calculateAmount>
          <currency>978</currency>
          <individualAmount>-10000</individualAmount>
          <billingType>1</billingType>
          <billingPeriodEndDate>20260214</billingPeriodEndDate>
          <extMvmtFinInstMode>8</extMvmtFinInstMode>
        <billingbatch>
                        <Account>1921</Account>                             
                        <Company>LNS</Company>
                        <TextCode>570</TextCode>
                        <TextData>952491</TextData>
        </billingbatch>

        <calculatebillingbatch>
                <Account>1921</Account>
                        <Centrum>LBNG</Centrum>
                        <Company>LNS</Company>
                        <TextCode>570</TextCode>
                        <TextData>952491</TextData>
        </calculatebillingbatch>
        </calculateAmount>
```

Comment: Look this: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hzGG32kz9nc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well use the identity transformation template

```
<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*| node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

and the template

```
<xsl:template match="billingbatch[Account = 1921]/Centrum"/>
```

Comment: if i want to delete "centrum" tag for two account no. like for 1921 and 5740 i dont want "centrum" tag then whats the changes in the code?

Comment: Use a predicate with an `or` condition: `<xsl:template match="billingbatch[Account = 1921 or Account = 5740]/Centrum"/>`.